# Every 30 minutes on the sharp

Tags: time, recurring-events

If the firework happens every 30 minutes from 7:00 7:30, 8:00, 8:30, ... 19:00
Can I say: There will be a fireworks display every half hour on the sharp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never heard *on the sharp* before. It would be more idiomatic as: *on the dot*, or 7:30 -- *sharp*.

For this pattern, you could say: 7:30 to 9:00, *on the half-hour*.

Some other ideas:

> *on the dot and the thirty(-minute mark)*,
>   *every half-hour, **punctually** or **precisely***

Comment: so can i just say: The firework happens on the half-hour. thx

Comment: @walterhuang Either "every half hour", or "on the half hour and the hour".

Comment: @user814064 thx

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "every half hour, on the half hour" has the exact meaning you are looking for here.

*Sharp* relates to punctuality, and as such "at 7:30 sharp" would suggest that failing to arrive at 7:30 would result in a sanction (if you were obligated to do something or be somewhere) or that you would not be waited for and so miss whatever the scheduled event was.

*On the dot* refers to precision, and as such "at 7:30 on the dot" would mean 7:30 precisely, and not 7:29 or 7:31. Just how precise such precision would be in practice is another matter, but the figurative "dot" here is the precise point in the line or field of possibility.

"On the sharp" is not an idiom on would use, the closest I can think of it is "on the sharp end" meaning the area within a field or issue with the most pressing difficulties.

Comment: thx for the explanation. i will vote you up when i got 15 rep